# How to import google app engine libraries in android studio?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to import the google app engine datastore api into my android studio project.

However when i paste

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.*;
```

Android studio don't want to import and say

```
unused importt statement
```

How can i fix it ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You can use what you imported.

Answer (score 0):

That API is for use within Google App Engine, and will not work in Android.

You shouldn't be accessing Cloud Datastore directly from an Android Application as it would mean anyone would be able to hack the Android client and issue arbitrary calls against your database.

I would instead suggest you look into something like [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) to create your own API exposes only the functionality you need as an API from App Engine - your Android app could then consume that API instead.